# Add-ADGroupMember variable type issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
$group_dn = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName
$gdn = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().displayName

write-host "gdn: " + $gdn

$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter { displayName -eq "GitHub Users" }
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User
```

My question is on how I can use $gdn instead of hardcoding "GitHub Users"

It seems to not like using it.  I tried $gdn.ToString(), [String]$gdn.  I am not really sure how to convert this so it will use it.

Comment: `$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter "displayName -eq '$gdn'"`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it is silly.  All you need to do is add double-quotes around the variable and it interpolates it for you:

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter { displayName -eq "$gdn" }
```

Comment: As a note, I'd avoid using scriptblocks for `-Filter` since it can result in some funky bugs and gets converted `ToString()` anyways.  Additionally, you can also use subexpressions if you need to access a member (`$($gdn.member)`) or if the characters after your variable are variable-valid characters, you can delimit your reference (`${gdn}`)